# Proving a complex equality.

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove the following equality:
$$2i\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{ia}{b}\right) = \log \left|\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right|$$
where $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R},a \neq \pm b$

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and that $\tan(x)=\sin(x)/\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_0^x \frac{1}{x^2-a^2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2a}\int_0^x \frac{1}{x-a} - \frac{1}{x+a} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2a} \log \left|\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right|$$

$$\int_0^x \frac{1}{x^2-a^2} \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^x \frac{1}{x^2+(ia)^2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{i}{a}\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{ix}{a}\right)$$

Comment: Although I think this is more than a hint...